# A particular homogenous travel accident insurance portfolio consists of $10,000$ policies

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

A particular homogenous travel accident insurance portfolio consists of $10,000$ policies issued within a period of one year. The probability that a randomly chosen insured will require the reimbursement of her/his losses in $0.2$%, and if a loss event has occured, then the amount of the loss is a uniform r.v $X$ ranging from $1000$ to $100,000$. Amounts of payoffs for different policies are independent.

Find the expected value of the payoff to a particular client.

**My Working:**

Since $X$ is uniform r.v then considering 1000 to be unit of money we have $X$~$UNI(1,100)$ and then the $E(X)=\frac{1+100}{2}=50.5$

Is my working and calculation okay? Kindly guide me in case I am wrong.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Probability theory, so I could be mistaken.  Your calculation seems off by a factor of $2$.  I get $$\frac{2}{1000} \times \frac{1000 + 100000}{2} = 101.$$

Comment: I don't get your calculation. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: I could be mistaken about the definition of "Expected Value Of a Payoff".  I am assuming that it equals chance of a payoff times expected size of a payoff (if a payoff occurs).  Given that I have never studied Probability theory, I could me misinterpreting the definition.  If instead, the definition is merely expected size of a payoff (if a payoff occurs), then your formula is correct and mine is wrong, except that your formula is then off by a factor of $1000$.

Comment: Re my last comment, since the random variable lies between $1000$ and $100000$, I am presuming that the average size of the random variable is $$\frac{1000 + 100000}{2} = 50500.$$  The chance of a payoff is $$\frac{2}{1000}.$$  This explains the math in my first comment, and the analysis in my second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note $X$ is a random variable for amount of loss if a loss event occurs. What you are interested in is expected payout to a client and so you need to multiply by the probability of a claim.

If $I$ is a random variable that indicates a loss with probability $p$ and $Y$ is a random variable for amount of payout for a claim,

$Y =  X \cdot I =  \left
\{\begin{array}
{1} 0 && \text {if }  I = 0 \ (\text {loss event does not occur}) \\ X && \text {if} \ I = 1 \ (\text {loss event occurs})
\end{array}
\right.$

$\mathbb{E}(Y) = p \cdot \mu_X$ where $\mu_X$ is the mean of $X$.

Here, $p = 0.002 \ $. Also as you rightly mentioned, given that $X$ is uniformly distributed between $1000$ to $100,000$

$\mu_X = \cfrac{1000 + 100000}{2}$
So, $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 0.002 \times \cfrac{1000 + 100000}{2} = 101$.